# Mapping Dictionary to custom object for TableView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, nsarray, nsdictionary

We have a custom Plist which contains data for a bunch of fields we are adding to a tableView. The layout is like this:

> Root Array
>   -- Section (Array)
>   --- Field (Dictionary)
>   ---- FieldName
>   ---- HasError
>   ---- FieldType
>   --- Field (Dictionary)
>   ---- FieldName
>   ---- HasError
>   ---- FieldType

There are multiple sections, with multiple fields in each. Each field is a dictionary, which we will later map to a custom object type. For example 'FieldObject'.

I understand we can create a custom initWithDictionary method on the 'FieldObject' to create a model object from each dictionary.

At the moment we get the relevant data like this:

```
 let tvDataPath = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("CandRegisterFields", ofType: "plist")
self.tableViewData = NSArray.init(contentsOfFile: tvDataPath!)
```

What we want to do is map all the dictionaries for the fields into the custom model object, then add them back into original `NSArray` data as the new object type in the same index etc. Is there a quick/easy way to do this?

Comment: why do you want to keep something in array then change it to something else? is there a reason for that? why not create a method that will map everything and put it into desired format in array?

Comment: @Lu_ - Really we just want an array of the model objects, the other array can be disregarded. So we have an array of dictionaries, we want an array of model objects.

Comment: @Lu_ - the problem I have is the syntax for the for statement loop. I.e. we start with an array of arrays (or an array of sections in terms of data). I want to loop each of the secondary arrays to find all the dictionaries, to map to objects

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why do you want to want to place your objects back into an `NSArray` wouldn't it be better to convert from cocoa objects into native swift collection types so you can use a struct rather than a class for your `Field` object?

For example:

```
struct Field
{
    let fieldName: String
    let hasError: Bool
    let fieldType: String //Should actually most likely be an enum
}

extension Field
{
    init?(dictionary: NSDictionary?)
    {
        guard let dictionary = dictionary, let fieldName = dictionary["FieldName"] as? String else { return nil }
        let hasError = dictionary["HasError"] as? Bool ?? false
        let fieldType = dictionary["FieldType"] as? String ?? ""
        self.init(fieldName: fieldName, hasError: hasError, fieldType: fieldType)
    }
}
```

Create a struct for your `Field` object. Have some init method that converts an `NSDictionary` into a `Field`.

```
var sectionsArray = [[Field]]()
for array in plistArray
{
    guard let array = array as? NSArray else { continue }
    let section = array.flatMap { Field(dictionary: $0 as? NSDictionary) }
    sectionsArray.append(section)
}
```

Iterate over the sections in your plist. Each of those sections is an array of dictionaries. You can map each of those dictionaries to a `Field` so your `[NSDictionary]` is mapped to a `[Field]`. You can then add that array to another array to retain the initial structure of the data.

Comment: Exactly that thank you, just needed some pointer on the syntax. I had it working similarly with NSArray but got their with your help, thanks. I used a class for the field model as items can change such as hasError. Thanks